# Android Custom MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, pan

I am trying to create an extended version of `MapView`.

The problem is when extended version of `MapView` is defined, mapview does not pan.

I am implementing an `onTouchListener` Inside my custom map view.

I also want to know is there any methods from where I can pan the mapview.

The problem does not persist when stock version of MapView is used with same source code.

**EDIT**

*MyMapView* source:

```
public class MyMapView extends MapView{

    public MyMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
        super(context, apiKey);

    }
    public MyMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }
    public MyMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            Log.v("MyMapView","Touched");
        }

        return false ;
    }



}
```

my `onCreate()` from `MapActivity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapper);
    mMapView=(MyMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapper_map);
    mMapView.setSatellite(false);       

}
```

Comment: I suspect it might be because you are returning true from some of your onTouch methods - try returning false; this should allow your class to do some stuff and then let the touch event propagate to the base class to do its stuff. But let's see your code.

Comment: @ John J Smith, code updated in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was casting it wrong.

```
mMapView=(MyMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapper_map);
```

should be

```
mMapView=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapper_map);
```

This solves the issue.

Thankx anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Your onTouchEvent() should return false, otherwise it will consume the event.

You can also instantiate a MapController and use it to change the view.  Here's a code snippet from an app I'm working on:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

    myMapView = (MapView) findViewById( R.id.myMapView );
    myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls( true );
    myMapController = myMapView.getController();

    myPoint = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
    myMapController.setCenter( myPoint );
    myMapController.zoomToSpan( 360 * MILLION, 360 * MILLION );
}
```

Comment: Its returning false. But still its now responding.